# iOS5 Display a MIME message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uiview, uilabel

I am looking for the best way to display a MIME message to the user. In fact, it is not an email message, it is a newsgroup (NNTP) message that is encapsulated in a MIME body. Currently I am displaying it in an UILabel but there are several problems, such as the quotation on replies and internal links. It would be great to display it similar to the built-in email app from Apple.

Does anyone have some suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I haven't tried it, I would guess a `WebView` could be best to handle this.

Comment: Thanks. FOR EVERYONE WHO NEEDS THIS: See my post below for further information.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have erased the MIME header from the message and set up a basic HTML structure using the following code in the ViewDidLoad...

```
//setting up html body
NSMutableString *body = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSString *head = @"<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><body>";
NSString *footer = @"</body></HTML>";

//css settings
NSMutableString *css = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[css appendString:@"word-wrap: break-word;"];
[css appendString:@"font-family: 'Helvetica', Verdana, Arial, serif;"];
[css appendFormat:@"font-size: 11pt;"];

//building html string
[body appendString:head];
[body appendFormat:@"<div style=\"%@\">", css];

NSString *HTMLbody = [MYPLAINTEXTBODYSTRING stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br/>"];  
[body appendString:HTMLbody];
[body appendString:@"</div>"];
[body appendString:footer];

self.MYSTRINGBODYPROPERTY = body;
```

... and load the before created body in the UIWebView.

```
[[[bodyWebView subviews] lastObject] setScrollEnabled:NO];

[bodyWebView loadHTMLString:self.body baseURL:nil];

[bodyWebView sizeToFit];
```

Now everything looks similar to Apples Mail App. Thanks.